# Single Model for create and update request with different validation strategy

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have an UserDTO. It is the same for both create and update requests but the problem is that the mandatory fields are different for different requests create and update. Suppose For create request townname, area and country are mandatory but for update request area and country are mandatory. If I apply @NotNull on any field it will apply for both request types. How can I handle this type of scenario?

```
public class UserDTO {

    private String id;

    private String townName;

    private String area;

    private String country;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation groups are the solution for this. This [link](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#using-validation-groups-to-validate-objects-differently-for-different-use-cases) helped me.

Create an interface for both create and update for validation grouping.

```
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public interface ValidationGroups {

    interface Create extends Default {

    }

    interface Update extends Default {

    }
}
```

Make changes in your controller class as shown below. Add @Validated at top of class and @Validated(Update.class) and @Validated(Create.class) in respective update and create methods.

```
@RequestMapping(BASE_PATH)
@Validated
public class UserController {

    @PutMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<UserDTO>> update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody @Validated(Update.class) UserDTO userDTO) {}
    
    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<UserDTO>> create(@RequestBody @Validated(create.class) UserDTO userDTO) {}
}
```

Now apply validations groups on respective fields. For common mandatory variables for both don't put any group on them or put both.

```
public class UserDTO {

    @NotNull(groups = Update.class)
    private String id;

    @NotNull(groups = Create.class)
    private String townName;

    // Either put both @NotNull(groups = {Create.class,Update.class}) or leave blank
    private String area;

    private String country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are addressing the same situation using separate Models. For example one for Create, one for Update. If there are many common validations for a field we set that in Base class